# .htaccess redirect for blackberry not working

Tags: .htaccess, blackberry, redirect

I am trying to redirect blackberry users to my mobile site by doing:

```
# redirect for blackberry users
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.BlackBerry.$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/m/ [R=301]
```

in my .htaccess, but nothing happens when I try to access from the device, I've already deleted cache and cookis and nothing works. I have been googling around and it seems I'm doing the redirect correctly but I guess not, what am I missing?

My .htaccess only contains that by the way.

**Edit**
The .htaccess in my server's root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this isn't the only rule in your .htaccess file, you might have an issue where a later rule messes up your redirect. To redirect immediately, you need to include the `L` flag.

I also suspect that your regular expression for the user agent is probably not correct for the input you're testing against, since the two `.` match just one character on either side of the word "BlackBerry". It would also be a good idea to guard against a redirect loop with a check to see if you're already in `/m/` (although if you have mod_rewrite directives in a .htaccess file in that directory it's not important).

Putting all of that together, we get something like the following:

```
# Check for x-wap-profile/Profile headers
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
# Check for BlackBerry anywhere in the user agent string
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}    BlackBerry [NC]
# Make sure we're not in /m/ already
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        !^/m/
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/m/ [R=301,L]
```

You may also want that `RewriteRule` to be...

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/m/$0 [R=301,L]
```

...if the content is named the same (but mobile-friendly) in the `/m/` directory.

Comment: even after I added that and tried on my blackberry it won't work, it's the only rule on my .htaccess so it shouldn't be messing up with anything =/ is there another reason it might not be working? I had never done this before to be honest

Comment: @Luis Armando: Hmm...Just to be sure, you have `RewriteEngine On` in there too right? I'm not seeing anything else that might be going wrong right now, unless for whatever reason the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is set to something weird, but that doesn't seem likely. I'll throw it on my test server later and see if my eyes are just missing something obvious though.

Comment: missing RewriteEngine On ... I feel so stupid :(, but thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Luis Armando: Ah, alright. No problem! I've also updated the answer to take into account what [Marc mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748325/3748870#3748870).

Comment: You might want to also include RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  at the beginning of the rule if you are trying to link to file (css, img, etc) outside of the /m/ directory. This will prevent the rule from applying to real files. Was banging my head till I realized that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your BlackBerry is not in "emulation mode" where it passes the user-agent for IE or Firefox instead of BlackBerry.  You can check in the browser's option screen.

A better way around this would be to base your rewrite rule on the "x-wap-profile" and/or "profile" headers, which the mobile browser should always send accurately.

Comment: how dow I do the rewrite on the x-wap-profile? just instead of Blackberry?